# Can I move to retrieve thrown weapons (Spears/Javelins) in combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, weapons, actions, throwing-things

I have a simple questions about throwing weapons specifically Javelins/Spears in DnD 5e. If I throw my Javelin at a enemy (regardless if it hits or miss and barring it falls off a cliff or something), can I still move in to retrieve it in combat? If I do, what action does that take up? Also if I throw two, can I retrieve both?

Comment: I think there are a lot of good questions here--I suggest you go ahead and post them separately. There's no stigma against multiple posts, and that way each can get the best attention it deserves. For instance (1) throw and retrieve; (2) Can I throw two/what feats or styles would be needed to throw two; (3) monk+javelin+off-hand.

Comment: okay then I'll rewrite the question and Post the others separately. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Regarding moving and interacting with objects, the Player's Handbook states:

> **You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or your action.** For example, you could open a door during your move as you stride toward a foe, or  you could draw your weapon as part of the action of the same action you use to attack. **If you want to interact with a second object, you need to use your action.**

Also, in the Movement and Position section of the PHB (page 196) we have (edited to only show relevant points):

> **Interacting With Objects Around You**
>
> Here are a few examples of the sorts of thing you can do in tandem with
> your movement and action:
>
> - . . .
> - draw or sheathe a sword
> - . . .
> - pick up a dropped axe
> - . . .

Using the above quotes:

> If I throw my Javelin at a enemy (regardless if it hits or miss and barring it falls off a cliff or something), can I still move in to retrieve it in combat?

Yes, I would definitely say picking up a spear/javelin on the ground counts as interacting with one object or feature of the environment.

> If I do, what action does that take up? Also if I throw two, can I retrieve both?

Picking up the first one can be done for free as part of your move. Picking it up could even be done for free as part of an attack action with it!

However, if you want to retrieve the second one in the same turn, you would need to pick one up for free during your move, and then take the "Interact with an Object" action to grab the other.

Comment: Thanks! That answered alot! So if I were to pick up the second weapon, it would count as a action.  But what if I have the Dual Wielder Feat, does that allow me to pick up two weapons for  free?

Comment: Dual wielder says "You can draw or stow two one-handed weapons when
you w ould normally b e able to draw or stow only one"; picking them up off the ground (or out of the orc) is neither drawing nor stowing.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the move action to get to the weapon, you would be using an "Use an Object" action (page 193 in the players' handbook):

> You normally interact with an object while doing something else, such as when you draw a sword as part of an attack. When an object requires your action for its use, you take the Use an Object action. This action is also useful when you want to interact with more than one object on your turn.

This is an action and you could retrieve both.

Your DM may rule that it would require a strength (or dexterity) check to wrench it free if it hit something and was stuck.